# Javascript- how can i extract datetime from ajax responsetext

Tags: javascript

Javascript- how can i extract datetime from this ajax responsetext:

```
This text was brought to you by AJAX 
Your request was received at:
Sunday 11 November 2018, 02:40:00 am
```

Comment: Is it one or three lines?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex to accomplish this. The regex:

```
/\w{3,6}day.*(?:am|pm)$/i
```

It starts by matching 3 or 4 `Word chars`, followed by `'day'`, then matches any number of `any char` until it reaches either `'am'` or `'pm'` and end of string. It uses the case inssensitive match.

How to use:

```
var text = 'This text was brought to you by AJAX' 
    + 'Your request was received at:'
    + 'Sunday 11 November 2018, 02:40:00 am'

var dateStr = text.match(/\w{3,4}day.*(?:am|pm)$/i);
var date = new Date(dateStr);
```

**Edit**:

Changed the quantifier to `{3,6}` so it matches `Wednesday` too.